# How to inject a command into a dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile where I want to RUN a bash command. This command can be different based on conditions. Therefore I had decided to pass this command as an argument.

Is it possible for me to inject an argument in RUN?

It would look like this:

```
RUN ${MYCOMMAND}
```

I also need to know if I can run multiple commands in the same layer of the dockerfile.

---

**Edit:-**

I need to install a bunch of apps similar to `pip install <app>`, in the dockerfile.

If I had 4 apps the command would look similar to this.

```
RUN pip install app_1 && \ 
    pip install app_2 && \ 
    pip install app_3 && \ 
    pip install app_4
```

However, the list of apps provided are dynamic.

Which is why I thought I could inject the entire set of command string as an argument.

Comment: It is somewhat possible (through the [`ARG` directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)). This sounds, however, like an [XY porblem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your use case?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'll update the question.

Comment: Typically, if you have a long list of things to install using pip, you'd do that by creating a file called requirements.txt, copying that file into the Docker container, and running `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a for loop. after passing the argument APP_LIST = "app1 app2 app3"

```
for app in ${APP_LIST}; do pip install $app; done
```